# Add fade-in/fade-out to background change

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, background-color

i'm pretty new to javascript but I finally could get this working. I can change the backgroundColor. But it's switching hard and I was wondering, if I can add a fade-in/fade-out if I change the backgroundColor from one to the other button.

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("tab2");

btn1.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    changeColor('blue');
});
btn2.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    changeColor('green');
});

function changeColor(color){
  var elem = document.getElementById( "area" );
  elem.style.backgroundColor =color;
```

I was also thinking about to change the colors to images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a transition to the element by CSS like this:

```
button {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
    transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

I recommend checking out [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transition` to animate a style change, then use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` to add/remove the classes that contain the new color.

```js
var btn1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("tab2");

btn1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  changeColor('blue');
});
btn2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  changeColor('green');
});

function changeColor(color) {
  var elem = document.getElementById("area");
  elem.classList.remove('blue', 'green')
  elem.classList.add(color);
}
```

```css
#area {
  padding: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='area'></div>
<button id='tab1'>button 1 </button>
<button id='tab2'>button 2 </button>
```